# Multiple INNER JOIN in sqldatasource for displaying in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, inner-join, sqldatasource

Almost everything is in the title, I'm trying to create a SQLdatasource in for displaying data from several tables in a gridview.

I have three tables in the model :

table lot_poudre with Id (primary key), reference, date_fabrication, ref_fab,  masse_reelle, projet_Id (foreign key to the Id of table projet)

table lot_element with Id (primary key), masse, lot_poudre_Id (foreign key to the Id of the lot_poudre table)

table projet with Id, nom

Here is what I've tried which works for displaying data from two tables (lot_poudre and lot_element) :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
        ID="SqlDataSourcelotspoudre"
        runat="server"
        ConnectionString="Data Source=GRE032477\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_pour_test;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        SelectCommand=
        "SELECT lot_poudre.Id,  lot_poudre.reference, lot_poudre.date_fabrication, lot_poudre.ref_fab,  lot_poudre.masse_reelle/Sum(lot_element.masse)*100 AS rendement, lot_poudre.masse_reelle AS masse_initiale
        FROM  

            lot_poudre INNER JOIN lot_element 
                ON lot_poudre.Id = lot_element.lot_poudre_Id 


        GROUP BY lot_poudre.Id,lot_poudre.reference, lot_poudre.date_fabrication, lot_poudre.ref_fab,lot_poudre.masse_reelle;"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The problem is when I try to display data from a third table like this (with table projet):

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource
        ID="SqlDataSourcelotspoudre"
        runat="server"
        ConnectionString="Data Source=GRE032477\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_pour_test;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        SelectCommand=
        "SELECT lot_poudre.Id,  lot_poudre.reference, lot_poudre.date_fabrication, lot_poudre.ref_fab, projet.nom, lot_poudre.masse_reelle/Sum(lot_element.masse)*100 AS rendement, lot_poudre.masse_reelle AS masse_initiale
        FROM projet 
         INNER JOIN 
            lot_poudre INNER JOIN lot_element 
                ON lot_poudre.Id = lot_element.lot_poudre_Id 
         ON projet.Id = lot_poudre.projet_Id

        GROUP BY lot_poudre.Id,lot_poudre.reference, lot_poudre.date_fabrication, lot_poudre.ref_fab,lot_poudre.masse_reelle, projet.nom;"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The error I get says name of object "projet" not valid.

I tried everything and need some help, the final gridviewI am trying to build displays values from 5 tables !!

Thanks

Boid'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner joins are incorrect.  Try this sql:

```
SELECT lot_poudre.Id,  
        lot_poudre.reference, 
        lot_poudre.date_fabrication, 
        lot_poudre.ref_fab, projet.nom, 
        lot_poudre.masse_reelle/Sum(lot_element.masse)*100 AS rendement, 
        lot_poudre.masse_reelle AS masse_initiale
        FROM projet 
         INNER JOIN lot_poudre ON projet.Id = lot_pourde.Id
         INNER JOIN lot_element  ON lot_poudre.Id = lot_element.lot_poudre_Id 
        GROUP BY lot_poudre.Id,lot_poudre.reference, lot_poudre.date_fabrication, lot_poudre.ref_fab,lot_poudre.masse_reelle, projet.nom
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two INNER JOINs before you have your first ON condition. Each join instance needs to be followed by the ON condition for that join, before the next INNER JOIN statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers,

I finally found what the problem was. In entityframework, you have to put "s" to some entities sometimes. In this case it worked ("s" added to "project").

There are two INNER JOINs before the first ON because I'm joining three tables. In microsoft Access, there is a parentheses to the "inner" INNER JOIN which makes it clearer to me.

```
"SELECT lot_poudre.Id,  lot_poudre.reference, lot_poudre.date_fabrication, lot_poudre.ref_fab, projets.nom, lot_poudre.masse_reelle/Sum(lot_element.masse)*100 AS rendement, lot_poudre.masse_reelle AS masse_initiale
        FROM lot_element
         INNER JOIN 
             lot_poudre INNER JOIN projets
                ON lot_poudre.projet_Id = projets.Id 
         ON lot_element.lot_poudre_Id = lot_poudre.Id

        GROUP BY lot_poudre.Id,lot_poudre.reference, lot_poudre.date_fabrication, lot_poudre.ref_fab,lot_poudre.masse_reelle, projets.nom"
```

This works as well (RickJames answer with added "s").

```
SELECT lot_poudre.Id,  
        lot_poudre.reference, 
        lot_poudre.date_fabrication, 
        lot_poudre.ref_fab,
        projets.nom, 
        lot_poudre.masse_reelle/Sum(lot_element.masse)*100 AS rendement, 
        lot_poudre.masse_reelle AS masse_initiale
        FROM projets 
         INNER JOIN lot_poudre ON projets.Id = lot_poudre.projet_Id
         INNER JOIN lot_element ON lot_poudre.Id = lot_element.lot_poudre_Id 
        GROUP BY lot_poudre.Id,lot_poudre.reference, lot_poudre.date_fabrication, lot_poudre.ref_fab,lot_poudre.masse_reelle, projets.nom"
```

Thanks everyone